# Jquery touchend firing before finger is released

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

I want to do Two things...do something when we touch the screen and when we release finger from screen..But touchend function below triggers alert box even before i release my finger.Where i am wrong ?

```
$(window).on('touchend', function(e){
alert("finger released");
});



$(window).on('touchstart', function(e){
//touch started
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152913) in webkit. Try to use `touchmove` instead if it suits your needs, or `touchcancel` is sometimes fired in place of `touchend`. BTW it works fine on Firefox (on Android at least, I don't even know if FF exists on iOS).

**EDIT**

What you can do also is playing around with `preventDefault();` on the `touchstart` event, but as it said by it's name, it prevents the default behavior, so once again, it depends on your needs.

Comment: i need something like keydown and keyup ... so on touchstart it should be keep on calling the function ...and on touchend it should alert....I am trying to create a game.

Comment: Like pressing a button ? In this case you could try putting a flag on... I think you gonna have to find a workaround... :( Did you tried `touchcancel` ? Why is `preventDefault()` not helpful ?

Comment: yea like pressing and holding a button...yea touchcancel is not triggering anything ..preventDefault() is also not helping

Comment: Again, *why* is `preventDefault()` not helpful ?

Comment: i used e.preventDefault() inside touchstart..but even before i release finger touchend is alerted...

Comment: That's strange, but as you can see in the link a posted in my answer, it's a known bug

Comment: @Vishnu I told you all I know about this. I solved my own problem by using `preventDefault()`, I can't tell more, sry. Maube you should take a look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) since it provides *sometimes* a better handling for those events. Or at least looking at the sources to see how it handles those things.